# What should I change in the query below?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
SELECT 
      ERI.ATTACK_CASE_ID, 
      LRM.REF_VALUE AS ATTACK_CASE_STATUS,
      WDR.RESTRICTION_NAME, 
    LL.USER_LABEL AS ***RESTRICTION_STATUS***,
     WSRI.RESTRICTION_DATE,
       CASE NVL(ERI.IS_PRIMARY, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE CASE ERI.IS_PRIMARY WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END END AS PRIMARY
FROM ALERT A 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ENTITY_RESTRICTION_INFO ERI ON A.ALERT_KEY=ERI.ENTITY_KEY
 LEFT OUTER JOIN LK_REFERENCE_MAPPING LRM ON LRM.REF_KEY= TO_CHAR(ERI.ATTACK_CASE_STATUS)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN LK_REFERENCE_CATEGORY LRG ON LRM.LK_REFERENCE_CATEGORY_ID = LRG.ID 
AND  LRG.CATEGORY_CODE = 'DD' 
AND LRG.SUB_CATEGORY_CODE='ATTACK_STATUS_ID_NAME'   
 LEFT OUTER JOIN WNORKOM_DD_RESTRICTION WDR ON ERI.RESTRICTION_ID=WDR.RESTRICTION_ID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN WNORKOM_SAR_RESTRICT_INFO WSRI ON WSRI.RESTRICTION_ID=ERI.RESTRICTION_ID
 *LEFT OUTER JOIN LK_LOOKUPS LL ON LL.CODE=**WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS***
WHERE A.ALERT_KEY=121234 
AND ERI.ATTACK_CASE_ID='PP-123-0980'
AND LL.TYPE=9502
```

The above query returns me all the records when there is some value in **WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS**

However, it returns NO RECORDS when **WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS** = NULL.
What can I add/change in above query so that LL.USER_LABEL = 'Unknown' when WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS = *NULL*. For your information, there is no value 'Unknown' in LK_LOOKUPS table. This is something I want to return as an independent string when **WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS** = *NULL*. Adding a record to LK_LOOKUPS table with LL.CODE=NULL and LL.USER_LABEL='Unknown' can mess up things so please help me passing it independently in the query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds you simply need to move the criteria `LL.Type = 9502` into the Left Join and use Coalesce in the Select clause. Also, since you are applying criteria to a column in the `Entity_Restriction_Info` table from the Where clause, you have transformed the Left Join to this table into an Inner Join and thus, you might as well use an Inner Join.

```
Select Eri.Attack_Case_Id
    , Lrm.Ref_Value As Attack_Case_Status
    , Wdr.Restriction_Name
    , Coalesce(LL.User_Label, 'Unknown') As Restriction_Status
    , Wsri.Restriction_Date
    , Case Nvl(Eri.Is_Primary, 0) 
        When 0 Then 'No' 
        Else Case Eri.Is_Primary 
                When 1 Then 'Yes' 
                Else 'No' 
                End 
        End As Primary
From Alert As A
    Inner Join Entity_Restriction_Info As Eri 
        On A.Alert_Key=Eri.Entity_Key
    Left Outer Join Lk_Reference_Mapping As Lrm 
        On Lrm.Ref_Key= To_Char(Eri.Attack_Case_Status)
    Left Outer Join Lk_Reference_Category As Lrg 
        On Lrm.Lk_Reference_Category_Id = Lrg.Id
            And  Lrg.Category_Code = 'Dd' 
            And Lrg.Sub_Category_Code='Attack_Status_Id_Name'   
    Left Outer Join Wnorkom_Dd_Restriction As Wdr 
        On Eri.Restriction_Id=Wdr.Restriction_Id 
    Left Outer Join Wnorkom_Sar_Restrict_Info As Wsri 
        On Wsri.Restriction_Id=Eri.Restriction_Id
    Left Outer Join Lk_Lookups As LL
        On LL.Code='Wsri.Restriction_Status'
            And LL.Type=9502
Where A.Alert_Key=121234 
    And Eri.Attack_Case_Id='Pp-123-0980'
```

Answer (score 0):

try (**EDIT - as per comment**):

```
SELECT 
      ERI.ATTACK_CASE_ID, 
      LRM.REF_VALUE AS ATTACK_CASE_STATUS,
      WDR.RESTRICTION_NAME, 
    DECODE ( WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS, NULL, 'Unknown', (SELECT USER_LABEL FROM LK_LOOKUPS LL WHERE LL.TYPE=9502 AND LL.CODE=WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS)) AS RESTRICTION_STATUS,
     WSRI.RESTRICTION_DATE,
       CASE NVL(ERI.IS_PRIMARY, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE CASE ERI.IS_PRIMARY WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END END AS PRIMARY
FROM ALERT A 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ENTITY_RESTRICTION_INFO ERI ON A.ALERT_KEY=ERI.ENTITY_KEY
 LEFT OUTER JOIN LK_REFERENCE_MAPPING LRM ON LRM.REF_KEY= TO_CHAR(ERI.ATTACK_CASE_STATUS)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN LK_REFERENCE_CATEGORY LRG ON LRM.LK_REFERENCE_CATEGORY_ID = LRG.ID 
AND  LRG.CATEGORY_CODE = 'DD' 
AND LRG.SUB_CATEGORY_CODE='ATTACK_STATUS_ID_NAME'   
 LEFT OUTER JOIN WNORKOM_DD_RESTRICTION WDR ON ERI.RESTRICTION_ID=WDR.RESTRICTION_ID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN WNORKOM_SAR_RESTRICT_INFO WSRI ON WSRI.RESTRICTION_ID=ERI.RESTRICTION_ID
WHERE A.ALERT_KEY=121234 
AND ERI.ATTACK_CASE_ID='PP-123-0980'
```

Comment: This will produce multiple equal rows if there are multiple rows in LK_LOOKUPS with TYPE=9502.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a record with LL.CODE=NULL wouldn't help you, as NULL=NULL is always null (hence false). You'll need to use a select expression:

Remove the `LEFT OUTER JOIN LK_LOOKUPS LL ON LL.CODE=WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS` and the `AND LL.TYPE=9502`, then change the `LL.USER_LABEL AS RESTRICTION_STATUS,` to:

```
IF(WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS IS NULL,
  "Unknown", 
  (SELECT USER_LABEL FROM LK_LOOKUPS LL
    WHERE LL.TYPE=9502 AND LL.CODE=WSRI.RESTRICTION_STATUS)
) AS USER_LABEL
```

Comment: Tsk -- this would work in mySQL. Oracle will need a CASE or DECODE instead of the IF. I have to leave that to you as an exercise :-) -- Apologies.

Comment: Thanks Jsalvata.. I used coalesce for LL.USER_LABEL, pulled out the LL.type=9502 from WHERE condition and added it to the JOIN.